# How do i stop the blocking of redirects in my chromedriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a scenario that clicks a button that performs a few redirects before landing on the intended page.

The issue is that these redirects get blocked within the Chromedriver session that is opened when the button is clicked.

Is there some sort of setting I can set for the Chromedriver so every time the script is run, the redirects don't get blocked?

Chrome version: 74.0.3729.157

**Code** tried :

```
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
```

This as far as i'm aware will only disable the popup blocking, not redirects? I've also tried within the session manually preventing the blocking of the redirects, but the next time i run the scenario the redirects are blocked again

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: I've got an argument set : options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");

This as far as i'm aware will only disable the popup blocking, not redirect blocking?

I've also tried within the session manually preventing the blocking of the redirects, but the next time i run the scenario the redirects are blocked again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable Safe Browsing in Chrome Settings:

Settings > Sync and Google services > Other Google services > Safe browsing

Or, try with this option

```
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the option that works. I figured that the chromedriver that is running isn't actually connected to where my options are set up...but it works when i set this option up in serenity.properties. Now to figure out why my options aren't connecting as i've set up....

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below to the driver, it works for me

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```